# How to Change The Background image size in Pyqt using css

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

**This is the main code**

```
# importing the required libraries

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        # set the title
        self.setWindowTitle("WebsiteBlocker")
        
        # setting window icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("logo.png"))
        
        # setting icon text
        self.setWindowIconText("logo")

        # setting the geometry of window
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 269, 495)
        style = open("style.css","r")
        self.setStyleSheet(style.read())
        # creating a label widget
        self.label_1 = QLabel("icon text ",self)
        # moving position
        self.label_1.move(100, 100)

        self.label_1.adjustSize()

        # show all the widgets
        self.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create pyqt5 app
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # create the instance of our Window
    window = Window()
    # start the app
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

**This is css code**

```
QLabel::hover
{
background-color : red;
/* background-image: url("404image.jpg"); */
/* z-index: auto; */
}
QMainWindow{
    background-image: url("back.jpg") 0,0,296,495;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

When i run this code i got this error and the image not fit to the aspect screen and also i tried the backgroud and used background image size property that also not working
`Unknown property background-size`
Is Ther any way to Solve this error in Pyqt

Comment: You cannot set the size of images set in Qt style sheets. The [Background](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#background) type for `background` and `background-image` only accepts the `Repeat` and `Alignment` properties after the url, and nothing else. Remember that Qt Style Sheets are just *based* on CSS, they are not a full implementation, that's why `background-size` is not recognized. See the whole documentation linked above to see all available properties (and which widgets/states/sub-controls support them).